# changing the orientation of a matplotlib 3d scatteplot displayed in kivy GUI

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy

I am trying to make a GUI to ingest excel files and get a 3d scatter plot using kivy and matplotlib. Although the plots are being displayed, I cannot change the orientation of the plot smoothly by dragging the displayed plot.

Here is the part of the code used to generate the plot:

```
*imports

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
X = np.arange(-508, 510, 203.2)
Y = np.arange(-508, 510, 203.2)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

Z = np.random.rand(6, 6)

ax.scatter(X, Y, Z)

ax.set_ylabel('Y [mm]')
ax.set_title('NAILS surface')
ax.set_xlabel('X [mm]')

canvas = fig.canvas


class LoadDialog(FloatLayout):
    load = ObjectProperty(None)
    cancel = ObjectProperty(None)


def callback(instance):
    # Clear the existing figure and re-use it
    plt.clf()

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = Axes3D(fig)

    X = np.arange(-508, 510, 203.2)
    Y = np.arange(-508, 510, 203.2)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

    Z = np.random.rand(6, 6)

    plt.scatter(X, Y, Z, alpha=0.8)

    ax.set_ylabel('Y [mm]')
    ax.set_title('NAILS surface')
    ax.set_xlabel('X [mm]')

    canvas.draw_idle()


class MatplotlibTest(App):
    title = 'Matplotlib Test'

    def build(self):
        fl = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        # a = Button(text="press me", height=40, size_hint_y=None)
        # a.bind(on_press=callback)

        fl.add_widget(canvas)
        # Clock.schedule_interval(callback, 1.0 / 6.0)
        # fl.add_widget(a)
        return fl


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MatplotlibTest().run()
```

Comment: The code is a slightly modified version of the code displayed in the following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624168/kivy-and-matplotlib-trying-to-update-plot-on-button-callback/38630095#38630095